# I have list of coordinates and My requirement is to arrange it

Tags: java, geometry, drawing, coordinates

I have list of coordinates to draw line.

Actually Problem is these coordinates are not in sequence.

Coordinate of endline is coordinates of startline for another line.
If any line's endline coordinates is not match with another line's start coordinates then create list of connected line.

Coordinates of lines are as startx,starty,endx,endy.

Below is list of lines coordinates.

3350 1500 3200 1500

1450 1750 1450 2200

1450 2200 2100 2200

2400 2200 2550 2200

2550 2200 2550 2350

2550 2350 2850 2350

2850 2350 2850 2700

2850 2700 3350 2700

3650 2700 3750 2700

3750 2700 3750 2600

3750 2600 5250 2600

5250 2600 5250 2350

5250 2350 5000 2350

4700 2350 4350 2350

4350 2350 4350 1600

4350 1600 3650 1600

3650 1600 3650 1500

3200 1500 3200 1750

3200 1750 1450 1750

Here last two line coordinates is actually on 2nd and 3rd position.

3200 1500 3200 1750

3200 1750 1450 1750

My requirement is to create all the bunch of lines which are connected to each other.

```
List<DeviceElement> outerListWire= new ArrayList<DeviceElement>(schematicImporter.listOfWires);
List<DeviceElement> innerListWire = new ArrayList<DeviceElement>(schematicImporter.listOfWires);
    List<DeviceElement> listWireTemp = new ArrayList<DeviceElement>();
for (int j = 0; j < outerListWire.size(); j++) {
    Wire wire1 = (Wire) outerListWire.get(j);
    for (int i = 0; i < innerListWire.size(); i++) {
        Wire wire2 = (Wire) innerListWire.get(i);

        if (wire1.getEndPoint().getX() == wire2.getStartPoint().getX() && wire1.getEndPoint().getY() == wire2.getStartPoint().getY() ) {
            if (!listWireTemp.contains(wire1)) {
                listWireTemp.add(wire1);
                System.out
                .println("wire1 = " + wire1.getStartPoint().toString() + " = " + wire1.getEndPoint().toString());
                innerListWire.remove(wire1);
            }

            if (!listWireTemp.contains(wire2)) {
                listWireTemp.add(wire2);
                System.out
                .println("wire2 = " + wire2.getStartPoint().toString() + " = " + wire2.getEndPoint().toString());
                innerListWire.remove(wire2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried above code but still coordinates list not getting in sequence.

Comment: Hello, could you explain with an example how the coordinates are expressed per row?

Comment: @mettleap I have update question. Please check.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash, I was going to say the same thing ...

Comment: @BhavinS. can ew assume that the coordinates on the first line are the start point?

Comment: Yes, coordinates on the first line are the start point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated based on the following assumptions:**

1. The first line of coordinates given in the question represents the coordinates of the first line in the set of connected lines
2. After finding the first set of connected lines, the first **unused** line of remaining lines of coordinates given in the question will be considered as the coordinates of the first line in the next set of connected lines and so on until the list of coordinates given in the question exhaust.

The required logic is in `Main.java`. I have also created `Point.java` and `Line.java` to test the logic. Feel free to let me know if you face any issue.

**Point.java**

```
public class Point {
    int x,y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }   
}
```

**Line.java**

```
public class Line {
    int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    Point start,end;
    boolean used;
    public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        super();
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }
    public Line(Point start, Point end) {
        super();
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    public int getX1() {
        return x1;
    }
    public void setX1(int x1) {
        this.x1 = x1;
    }
    public int getY1() {
        return y1;
    }
    public void setY1(int y1) {
        this.y1 = y1;
    }
    public int getX2() {
        return x2;
    }
    public void setX2(int x2) {
        this.x2 = x2;
    }
    public int getY2() {
        return y2;
    }
    public void setY2(int y2) {
        this.y2 = y2;
    }
    public Point getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    public void setStart(Point start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
    public Point getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
    public void setEnd(Point end) {
        this.end = end;
    }
    public boolean isUsed() {
        return used;
    }
    public void setUsed(boolean used) {
        this.used = used;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Line [x1=" + x1 + ", y1=" + y1 + ", x2=" + x2 + ", y2=" + y2 + "]";
    }   
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Line> givenLines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        givenLines.add(new Line(3350, 1500, 3200, 1500));
        givenLines.add(new Line(1450, 1750, 1450, 2200));
        givenLines.add(new Line(1450, 2200, 2100, 2200));
        givenLines.add(new Line(2400, 2200, 2550, 2200));
        givenLines.add(new Line(2550, 2200, 2550, 2350));
        givenLines.add(new Line(2550, 2350, 2850, 2350));
        givenLines.add(new Line(2850, 2350, 2850, 2700));
        givenLines.add(new Line(2850, 2700, 3350, 2700));
        givenLines.add(new Line(3650, 2700, 3750, 2700));
        givenLines.add(new Line(3750, 2700, 3750, 2600));
        givenLines.add(new Line(3750, 2600, 5250, 2600));
        givenLines.add(new Line(5250, 2600, 5250, 2350));
        givenLines.add(new Line(5250, 2350, 5000, 2350));
        givenLines.add(new Line(4700, 2350, 4350, 2350));
        givenLines.add(new Line(4350, 2350, 4350, 1600));
        givenLines.add(new Line(4350, 1600, 3650, 1600));
        givenLines.add(new Line(3650, 1600, 3650, 1500));
        givenLines.add(new Line(3200, 1500, 3200, 1750));
        givenLines.add(new Line(3200, 1750, 1450, 1750));

        int linesIndex, usedCounter=0;
        List<List<Line>> listOfConnectedLines = new ArrayList<List<Line>>();

        //The start (first) line, in the list of given lines, to be processed to find the first set of connected lines
        Line startLineforTheNextSetOfConnectedLines=givenLines.get(0);
        startLineforTheNextSetOfConnectedLines.setUsed(true);
        usedCounter = 1;        

        //Process the list of given lines until all the lines have been used to form the connected lines
        while (usedCounter < givenLines.size()) {

            linesIndex = 0;         
            List<Line> connectedLines = new ArrayList<Line>();
            connectedLines.add(linesIndex, startLineforTheNextSetOfConnectedLines);     
            Line nextLine=null;

            //Starting with startLineforTheNextSetOfConnectedLines, the variable lastArrangedLine will hold the next lines qualifying to become the connected line 
            Line lastArrangedLine=startLineforTheNextSetOfConnectedLines;

            //Create the list of connected lines starting with startLineforTheNextSetOfConnectedLines
            for (int i = 0; i < givenLines.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < givenLines.size(); j++) {
                    nextLine=givenLines.get(j);
                    if (!nextLine.isUsed() && lastArrangedLine.getX2() == nextLine.getX1()
                            && lastArrangedLine.getY2() == nextLine.getY1()) {
                        nextLine.setUsed(true);
                        usedCounter++;
                        connectedLines.add(++linesIndex, nextLine);
                        lastArrangedLine = nextLine;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Add the list of connected lines (found from the above nested for loops) to the list of connected lines
            listOfConnectedLines.add(connectedLines);

            //Find the start (first) line for the next set of connected lines
            for (int i = 0; i < givenLines.size(); i++) {
                if(!givenLines.get(i).isUsed()) {
                    startLineforTheNextSetOfConnectedLines=givenLines.get(i);
                    startLineforTheNextSetOfConnectedLines.setUsed(true);
                    usedCounter++;                  
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Display the lists of connected lines
        for(List<Line> connectedLines:listOfConnectedLines)
            System.out.println(connectedLines);
    }
}
```

**Output for the given list of lines:**

```
[Line [x1=3350, y1=1500, x2=3200, y2=1500], Line [x1=3200, y1=1500, x2=3200, y2=1750], Line [x1=3200, y1=1750, x2=1450, y2=1750], Line [x1=1450, y1=1750, x2=1450, y2=2200], Line [x1=1450, y1=2200, x2=2100, y2=2200]]
[Line [x1=2400, y1=2200, x2=2550, y2=2200], Line [x1=2550, y1=2200, x2=2550, y2=2350], Line [x1=2550, y1=2350, x2=2850, y2=2350], Line [x1=2850, y1=2350, x2=2850, y2=2700], Line [x1=2850, y1=2700, x2=3350, y2=2700]]
[Line [x1=3650, y1=2700, x2=3750, y2=2700], Line [x1=3750, y1=2700, x2=3750, y2=2600], Line [x1=3750, y1=2600, x2=5250, y2=2600], Line [x1=5250, y1=2600, x2=5250, y2=2350], Line [x1=5250, y1=2350, x2=5000, y2=2350]]
[Line [x1=4700, y1=2350, x2=4350, y2=2350], Line [x1=4350, y1=2350, x2=4350, y2=1600], Line [x1=4350, y1=1600, x2=3650, y2=1600], Line [x1=3650, y1=1600, x2=3650, y2=1500]]
```

Comment: Every time this code give only first list of connected lines.
Goal is to find all the connected lines.